# Kernel of Zassenhaus Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

Good morning everyone, I need a little verification:

This is from Zassenhaus Lemma. Let $H', H, K',$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $H'$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ and $K'$ is a normal subgroup of $K$. Set $J = (H \cap K')(H' \cap K)$. Define the function $f: H'(H\cap K) \rightarrow (H\cap K)/J$ as follows: If $a \in H'(H\cap K)$, then $a = h'b$, where $h' \in H'$ and $b \in H \cap K$. Set $f(a)=Jb$. It is already proven that the function $f$ is well defined and a homomorphism.

I want to verify that $\rm Ker(f) = H'(H \cap K')$.
If $a \in H'(H \cap K')$ then $a = h'c$, where $h' \in H'$ and $c \in H \cap K' .$
So, $f(a)=Jc$ . but $c \in H \cap K'$, thus by applying group absorption law, $f(a)=Jc=J$ (the identity).

Is this correct? If it is incorrect, please provide a correct one.

Comment: It's the afternoon where I am.

Comment: @Shaun sending the goodness of the morning from where I am, keep it!

Comment: I think [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413409/proof-of-zassenhaus-lemma?rq=1) is the answer to your question.